# AngularJs toggle template with directive to create notification like stackoverflow

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a notification system in AngularJs just like the notification used here. When there is a new comment, answer, etc.. The archive icon shows a red sign with the number of activities, and when I click on it, it opens up a box with the last notifications.

To do this, I built this simple directive to dynamic loads a templateUrl:

html:

```
<li test-alert ref="msg">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
</li>
<li test-alert ref="bell">
    <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
</li>
```

directive:

```
angular
    .module('agApp')
    .directive('testAlert', testAlert)
;

/* @ngInject */
function testAlert() {
    var templateA = '<div>Test template A</div>';
    var templateB = '<div>Test template B</div>';
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            ref: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope,element,attrs,controller){
            scope.showAlert = false;
            element.on("click", function() {
                if (scope.ref == 'bell') {
                    scope.showAlert = true;
                    element.append(templateA);
                    scope.$apply();
                } else {
                    scope.showAlert = true;
                    element.append(templateB);
                    scope.$apply();
                };
                console.log(scope.ref);
            });
            element.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                    scope.showAlert = false;
                }
            });
        }
    };
}; //end test alert
```

But I'm with some problems..

- If i click on the icon to open the template it will open, but every time i click on it, it will append another template. Id' like it to change (if it's the other template) or do nothing.
- When it is opened, I can't make it close. I can use a 'close' button, but I'd like to close/remove the template when the user click on the document or press esc;
- The code I tried to use to close on 'Esc' key, doesn't work.

My main objective is to create a notification system just like the one in stackOverflow, so is this the best way to do it? Should I use a controller instead?

---

#### Edit:

Close mechanism I'm using at the momment. It's working, but maybe it can be improved.

run.js

```
angular
.module('agApp')
.run(runApp);


/* @ngInject */
function runApp($rootScope) {

    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 27) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast("escapePressed", e.target);
        };
    });
    document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("documentClicked", e.target);
    });


}; //end run
```

controller.js

```
$rootScope.$on("documentClicked", _close);
$rootScope.$on("escapePressed", _close);
function _close() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        vm.closeAlert();
    });
};
```

Since I wasn't able to use it as a directive, I moved the open/close function inside a controller. But it can be used in any other way, as long as it works, there is no problem.

Comment: Should each instance of the directive be able to show two different templates? Or is one template per directive enough?

Comment: @tasseKATT At the momment, I'm using 2, because one of them is for notifications and the other is for messages. But I'm considering using only one with a ng-if statement inside the template to show either the notification list or message, based on the param sent by the directive.

Comment: I assume the envelope is for messages and the bell for notifications. But you are using the directive twice, and each directive has two templates, which equals four. Can they be combined into one directive or do you want to keep them separated?

Comment: @tasseKATT This can be as simple as it's possible. As long as i achieve the result, it's ok. I'm starting to try to develop modules now, so I don't know the proper logic/workflow very well. It was my first attempt, so.. any improvement is welcome! :)

Comment: Added an answer with an example. Let me know if you had something else in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, key events only fire on the document and elements that may receive focus.

Directives are really nice for things you need to use multiple times. But even if you implement your notification system as a directive and only use it once - you will have it isolated, which is often good.

Hard to give the best solution without knowing more but here is one example that implements the messages and the notifications as one directive:

```
app.directive('notifications',
  function() {

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {

        scope.viewModel = {
          showTemplateA: false,
          showTemplateB: false
        };

        scope.toggleTemplateA = function() {

          scope.viewModel.showTemplateA = !scope.viewModel.showTemplateA;

          scope.viewModel.showTemplateB = false;
        };

        scope.toggleTemplateB = function() {

          scope.viewModel.showTemplateB = !scope.viewModel.showTemplateB;

          scope.viewModel.showTemplateA = false;
        };

      }
    };
  });
```

It simply contains logic for showing and hiding the templates. The directive uses a template that looks like this:

```
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" ng-click="toggleTemplateA()"></i>
  <div ng-show="viewModel.showTemplateA">
    Template A
  </div>
  <br>
  <i class="fa fa-bell-o" ng-click="toggleTemplateB()"></i>
  <div ng-show="viewModel.showTemplateB">
    Template B</div>
</div>
```

The template uses `ng-show` and `ng-click` to bind to our scope functions. This way we let Angular do the job and don't have to mess around with `element.append` etc.

Usage:

```
<notifications></notifications>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/8M1D5uENjpDoIbb1ZuMR?p=preview

---

To implement your closing mechanism you can add the following to the directive:

```
var close = function () {

  scope.$apply(function () {
    scope.viewModel.showTemplateA = false;
    scope.viewModel.showTemplateB = false;
  });
};

$document.on('click', close);

$document.on('keyup', function (e) {

  if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    close();
  }
});

scope.$on('$destroy', function () {

  $document.off('click', close);
  $document.off('keyup', close);
});
```

Note that you now have to inject `$document` into the directive:

```
app.directive('notifications', ['$document',
  function($document) {
```

In the toggle functions you can call `stopPropagation()` to prevent the global closing handler to execute when you click the icons (might not be needed in this example, but good to know. Might want it on the actual templates in the future?):

```
scope.toggleTemplateA = function($event) {

          $event.stopPropagation();
```

And:

```
ng-click="toggleTemplateA($event)"
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/LHS4RBE7qtY4yNyEdR16?p=preview

Comment: What about the closing mechanism? I noticed it will close if i click again on the icon. Perfect! I didn't had it before. But I'd like to be able to close if the user clicks else where but the message box, or with a esc key press. I edit my question to show what i did to make this function.

Comment: Thank you very much!! This is great! I also think I'll use it for other purposes. For example, I have a mobile 'extra' menu, it will open a modal window with secundary options. This directive can be easily modified to open the other template, right? Just have to make the proper name calls and load the correct template. Or even improve it to pass the template and name via scope value as attr in the directive. Is that correct?

Comment: You're welcome :) Yes, that is of course possible. But only do it if the logic in the link function is shared. Otherwise make a new directive for the other templates.

Comment: Oh, of course, i meant to use the same logic used in this directive, but another one, for example, 'extraMobileMenu' directive to load the mobile menu. But thanks again.